# How to create object for each nested object in large object and add it to Redux state?

Tags: json, reactjs, object, redux

**I have the following Action:**

```
export const contextualize = (data) => {
    return {
        type: 'CONTEXTUALIZE',
        payload: data,
    }
}
```

**Here is my current reducer:**

```
const contextReducer = (state=null, action) => { // NEED TO UNPACK PAYLOAD
    switch(action.type){
        case 'CONTEXTUALIZE':
            state =  action.payload
            return state
        default:
            return state
    }
}

export default contextReducer
```

**My Payload looks like this. It is a 4 level nest object:**

```
{
    {
    contextA: {
        A: 'Bar',
        }
        {
        B: 'Boo'
        }
    }

    {
    contextB: {
        C: 'Bee',
        }
        {
        D: 'Bad'
        }
    }

    {
    contextC: {
        E: 'Bay',
        }
        {
        F: 'Bat'
        }
    }

}
```

I believe I need to do this with nested for loops, but **I am unsure how to create a new object out of each inner most object with the corresponding value and add the object to my state**.

For example with the payload above I want to achieve this:

`state = {'A': 'Bar'}, {'B': 'Boo'}, {'C': 'Bee'}` etc

The point is I wanted to be able to access each inner most object individually from my Redux global state without having to use syntax like this since it is redundant and my actual key names are far longer:

`BigObject.contextA.B`

Answer (score 0):

You can destructure the payload and then spread the resulting objects into your state.

The example state you provided isn't a valid javascript object but assuming your payload looks something like:

```
const examplePayload {
  contextA: {
    A: 'Bar',
    B: 'Boo'
  },
  contextB: {
    C: 'Bee',
    D: 'Bad',
  },
  contextC: {
    E: 'Bay',
    F: 'Bat'
  }
}

const contextReducer = (state=null, action) => { // NEED TO UNPACK PAYLOAD
    switch(action.type){
        case 'CONTEXTUALIZE': {
            const {contextA, contextB, contextC} = action.payload;
            return {...contextA, ...contextB, ...contextC};
        }
        default:
            return state
    }
}

export default contextReducer
```